# JSON parse using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON string using $.getJSON. The string structure is this:

```
{"status":"1","dati":[{"id":"259","temperatura":"27.5\u00b0C","localita":"Perugia (PG)","distanza":"8.94","altitudine":"493","pioggia":"0.0","pressione":"1013.5","vento":"12.9","minima":"15.9","massima":"27.5","orario":"12\/07\/2013 17.35","url":"http:\/\/www.perugiameteo.it\/standardpage.aspx?id=56","webcam":"http:\/\/www.perugiameteo.net\/webcam\/webcam.jpg","raffica":"30.6","rate":"0.0"}]}
```

and this is the code that I'm trying to use, but without success (I obtain an undefined value)

```
<ul id="groups"></ul>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var $grouplist = $('#groups');
       $.getJSON("URL_FILE", function(MyData){
           $.each(MyData.dati, function() {
           $('<li>' + this.localita + '</li>').appendTo($grouplist);
           });
       });
    });
</script>
```

Any helps? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a typo -- should be "MyData", not "myData".

Comment: And `$('<li />', {text: obj.localita}).appendTo($grouplist);`, but first open the console and check for errors, and chain on a fail function to that ajax call.

Comment: @Kevin B : Was a my mistake writing the code here, but this is not the error: ;)

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/Zu82C/ inspect the ajax call to make sure it works.

Comment: With the string it work.. but if I call the string on external file... it doesn't work... try here:
http://jsfiddle.net/andrea75/8X4As/

Comment: @Andrea75 - Did you include jQuery?

Comment: @Andrea75 that fiddle works too... Your ajax call must not be returning what you think it should.

Comment: @Andrea75 - do you have `Fiddler` so you can 'see' what is coming back from you `AJAX` call?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Yes, I include jQuery... but for me doesn't work.. :(

http://jsfiddle.net/andrea75/8X4As/

Comment: Andrea...the jsfiddle you posted will not work because of cross-domain issues.  In the console, this error comes up: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mobile.lineameteo.it/rete_temperaturaDatiWebcam.php?lat=43.08&lon=12.34&limit=1. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @Andrea75 - Use the jsFiddle JSON echo API if you want to fetch a JSON from other domain.

Comment: @Andrea75 Do you have control over this JSON service? Or is it some external site from you? If possible, you could have the server support JSONP

Comment: OK! SOLVED! 
It work launching all on my local server with relative path instead absolute path! ;) I don't know why, but in this way it work fine! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have proven via jsfiddles in the comments that it works with local data, then it is obviously an `AJAX` issue.

Install [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) so you can watch the traffic and make the request yourself through Fiddler. It will show the payload being returned.